# Exclude folder in .gitignore but include files starting with a certain prefix

Tags: git, github

```
/objects/
    /Contact/
        npe01__AlternateEmail__c.xml
        FundId.xml
        npe01__Age__c.xml
    /npe01__OppPayment__c/
        PaymentId.xml
        npe01__Origin.xml
```

Here, I want to ignore the all the files starting with **npe01** but exclude the folder starting with  **npe01**. Therefore, as per above folder structure, the file **npe01__Origin.xml** should be ignored however the folder **npe01__OppPayment__c** and the file **PaymentId.xml** should be excluded.

I have used the .gitignore file like this -

```
**npe01__* 
!objects/npe01__OppPayment__c*
```

However this doesnt seem to work

Answer (score 0):

I created a test repo with this file structure. Using VSCode to show what's excluded (in grey) in `.gitignore`.

Start off by ignoring all folders & files that start with `npe01*`:

[image: Primary name pattern to ignore.]

The file `PaymentId.xml` is ignored because it's in a folder that matches the initial ignore directive.

Now allow the specific folder `!/objects/npe01__OppPayment__c/`. You'll see only the files in that folder that match the previous line(s) in `.gitignore` are ignored. `PaymentId.xml` is now part of the repo.

[image: Allow specific folder path]